# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure after upgrade to TLSv1.2

Tags: java, linux, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am working on a Java 1.7 application on a Linux Centos server that connects to a third party using SOAP. Everything was working until the third party upgraded their SSL from TLSv1.1 to TLSv1.2. Now when we try to call their service, we get:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://webservices.abc.company.com: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

We also have another Linux Centos server, that uses the exact same code base, but it can call the SOAP service with no errors. So I have tried to compare to find any differences. The differences I can find is that some of the directory structures are different, but the files I think are applicable are the same.  For example,

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

Are both in the same place, and both have the same ciphers:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
#SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

They both have the same certificate issued by the third party company.

```
/etc/httpd/ssl/abc.crt
```

I have stopped the firewall.

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

**Question**

Do you know where else I can look, and what I can try?

Comment: This might help in your case: https://superuser.com/questions/747377/enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-for-clients-on-java-7

Comment: I have noticed on the server that gets the error, it has:  `echo $MAVEN_OPTS
-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` and the server that has no error: `echo $MAVEN_OPTS
-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=2048m`

Comment: I have tried setting `$JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`, and restarting apache karaf (where the SOAP client resides), but there is no difference.

Comment: v1.1 is deprecated. You need to update gnutls or openssl and make sure you are specifying v1.2 ciphers.

Comment: I am using openssl, the latest version though.